# How to use the PROGRAM STATUS clause in a COBOL program

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

How to use the PROGRAM STATUS clause in a COBOL program to control the errors. According to the IBM manuals (like https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasb/sc092539.pdf), the PROGRAM STATUS clause specifies a data item into which values from the predefined program status structure are moved after an error occurs in the program.

Comment: It does not appear to be able _to control ... errors_, but rather to report them. There is a minimal example of _How to use_ [here](https://www.itjungle.com/2013/05/01/fhg050113-story02/). Scroll down a bit to see the example.

Comment: @RickSmith Thank you for this. Very useful. Why you use a comment instead of as an answer?

Comment: I think that an answer should include how using `PROGRAM STATUS` would be useful to the programmer. That is, an error has been reported; now, what should be done with that error information? I do not have that knowledge for iSeries COBOL.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/apiref/apiexusapi.htm It appears to show to to put an error handler in place.

Comment: @HiginioFuentes After reading the docs and possibly after testing you may be able to come up with a minimal sample that shows how to use this feature and create an own answer this way.